# Compare two arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, comparison

After comparison between an array `total= np.full((3,3),[0, 1, 2])` and array `a = np.array([1],[0],[1])`, I am looking to get a `new_array`:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

Comment: Please explain the relationship between the input and output. You've got two answers that take two different interpretations of what you want, and it's not clear whether either of them performs the operation you actually want.

Comment: Both are correct

Comment: Both of them produce the output you specified for this particular pair of inputs, but `return np.array([[0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 2]])` would also do that. They don't behave the same way as each other on other outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
import numpy as np

total= np.full((3,3),[0, 1, 2])
a = np.array([[1],[0],[1]])

new_array = np.array([np.delete(l, i) for l,i in zip(total,a)])
```

**result**

```
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can apply a mask and reshape:

```
import numpy as np

total= np.full((3,3),[0, 1, 2])
a = np.array([[1],[0],[1]])

a = np.repeat(a, 3, axis=1)
new_total = total[total!=a].reshape(3, 2)

>>> print(new_total)
[[0 2]
 [1 2]
 [0 2]]
```